# Microsoft SQL Server 2008 error when restoring database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've just recently upgraded to SQL Server 2008 from 2005 and when I attempt to restore a database I get the following error...

"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Sqm, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of what the exact problem was but I went with the solution of uninstalling SQL Server completely then re-installing.  These are the steps I followed...

1. I uninstalled everything SQL Server related I could find in add/remove programs.
2. Ran "CCLeaner" both for programs/windows components and the registry
3. Removed any left over SQL Server folders from my hard drives which seemed to be from previous SQL Server installations.
4. Re-install SQL Server 2008.

And voila everything works.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error after a clean install of Sql Server 2008 Express Edition after trying to create a new database.

These are the steps I followed and it worked for me using Windows 7 64 Bit:

1. Copy the file Microsoft.SqlServer.Sqm.dll located on C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared
2. to folder C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE
3. and C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE.

Then next time I tried to add a database everything came up fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the exact verion 10.0.*.* was not found in the folder where 'ssms.exe' is present.

*Solution*

Goto the exact folder where 'ssms.exe' is present by going to start menu and typing ssms.exe. then right click the result and click 'open file location'.

In that location try to paste the exact 10.0.*.* version of 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Sqm'.

you can find the exact version somewhere by searching in the Microsoft Sql Server folders.

In my case it asked for 12.0.0.0 version and i pasted 12.0.2000.8 and it worked like a charm.!!!! cheers.!!!